# Is there any way to set days in delayed chained payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Actually, as per my requirement I need to set days in delayed chained payment. Suppose, we need to set 10 days, so within 10 days if admin transfer the amount, so no transfer further required other than that after 10 days that amount will automatically transfer to the merchant account.

Is this possible, so please tell me the full process.

Comment: Try and avoid asking for "full process". keep questions specific as it shows that you done the necessary research

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible the maximum is 90 days. "Payments to secondary receivers can be delayed for up to 90 days."

For a full explanation check Paypal documentation @https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/?mark=delayed

Comment: Its part of the adaptive payment API, its not really a setting you set.

Look at step 4 on link posted on this answer "it says When the time comes to pay secondary receivers, call ExecutePayment" So its up to you, aslong as its within the 90 days